# Android open listview item in new activity and swipe through the listview items in the activity

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, swipe-gesture

i have a `ArrayList<Movies>` and populate a ListView with the items in the ArrayList. If im clicking on an item in the ListView, im starting a new activity (lets call it "OpenMovieActivity") and put some information to the new aktivity like:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Context, RateMovieActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("bitmapInfo", bi.key);
            intent.putExtra("MovieID", movie.ID);
            intent.putExtra("MovieTitle", movie.Name);
            intent.putExtra("MovieGenre", movie.Genre);
            intent.putExtra("MovieRating", movie.Rating);

            Context.startActivity(intent);
```

Everything is working fine but if i want to open the movie from the next listview item i have to go back and click on the next item to open it.

I want to swipe left and right in the OpenMovieActivity to open a the item before or after the just opend item. I guess its not possible by putting the information with "putExtra".

Does somebody has any idea how i have to do that?

Comment: You can manage horizontal listview once OpenMovieActivity is opened !

Comment: Read about viewPager https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging

Answer (score 0):

You should try using ViewPager where you can insert the items of ArrayList in PagerAdapter and while clicking on the list view item you can directly jump on that item of the page in the ViewPager Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to transport your listView data with intent or other way

then add horizontal listView in your detail view

after clicking the horizontal item get object and refresh view of detail view

shown like below image..

[image]